# SaveToLayerFile_management() gives 732 error when input layer name contains forward slash char

Tags: python, arcmap

My code:

```
#  Change Feature Classes to Relative Path Lyr files

import arcpy, csv, os
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
messageStr = str(mxd)
arcpy.AddMessage(messageStr)
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\GeneralWorkData\\ArcGIS Test Data\\Test Data From,to Martin B\\Relative_Paths_Lyr_Files"
for fc in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
  fc = str(fc)
  out_layer = fc + ".lyr"
  arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(fc,out_layer,"RELATIVE")
  messageStr = out_layer
  arcpy.AddMessage(messageStr)
```

This loops round all the layer names in the currently loaded data. Works fine until it hits layer called "Observed pipeline/cable", and gives the following message:

> ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset Observed pipeline/cable does not exist or is not supported". Failed to execute (SaveToLayerFile)."

Is it thinking the forward slash is part of a directory(which it isn't)? What do I do to make SaveToLayerFile() accept the forward slash as part of the layer name?

Answer (score 0):

Gotta do something with that metacharacter. Probably best to replace with an underscore, `fc.replace('/','_') + '.lyr'`. Could try to insert a backslash to escape the interpretation of that character but that could get messy.